# How to implement 'Select All' for TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

I have an application which has a modified tiny_mce (version 3.0.1). It was modified and has a file upload function and that's why I can't upgrade tiny_mce. It works well except for Internet Explorer 9. In IE9, the cursor is not displayed and I can't write anything.

I found workarounds.

- Make the site compatibility mode
- Right-click the editing area and click 'Select All'

The second workaround is better. How do I select all programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The second workaround is better. How do I select all programmatically?

This depends on the point of time you want to "select all".

Here is the necessary code:

```
   tinymce.get('my_editor_id').getBody().select();
```

To do this right after initialization the code is:

```
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
           ed.getBody().select();
      });
   }
```